# Is it possible to use server flow auth as a fallback for client side auth on Google Drive for browser that do not support the JavaScript libraries?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

The [list of supported browsers for the Google API JavaScript library](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/) used to implement Google Drive functionality directly in JavaScript doesn't officially support IE 7- or Opera, of note.

If I wanted to use the JS library, with a server-based fallback for unsupported browsers, is that possible?

The obvious issue is that separate API keys for the client and server flow auth would be needed, so if the scopes were limited to files opened and created by the Drive app, would a file created in IE 7 using the server auth open in Chrome using the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'hybrid' auth using both client-flow and server-flow works OK. The JS client and CORS endpoints aren't all in place yet, so I use JS where I can, but proxy through my servlets where necessary.

I use a single client-id for both.